# Windows Store - Publish VSTS release step fails because package "...must be uniquely identified by their full names"

Tags: uwp, azure-devops, windows-store, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I've created a VSTS release to deploy my app to the Windows store using the Windows Store - Publish step (previously installed).  I have the connection and things all set up, and it creates a submission, but it fails because of these errors:

> Appx packages (including previously published and currently uploaded) must be uniquely identified by their full names. You have provided two packages with the full name** EagleBusinessSoftware.EBMSMyTime1.5_1.225.45.0_Neutral_~ which have different contents. Please remove one of these packages, or increment current package versions to continue.

If I open the Dev Dashboard, I see the submission and these errors.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted the Windows Developer support, and they were super helpful!  I just needed to go to the submission in the dashboard, open the Packages page, and click Save.

This is sad, because it now is not fully automated.  If someone has a better solution, I would be all ears.